# Topology on the space of test functions

Tags: distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I try to read into the theory of distributions and there is one thing which bothers me. I read that a distribution is a linear, continuous functional from the space of test functions, which, depending on the author, is sometimes defined as the Schwartz space and sometimes as $C^\infty_K$ (smooth functions with compact support).

For starters, where does this ambiguity come from and does it matter?

Now for the case $C^\infty_K$, I found two definitions of the associated topology.  One as the final topology induced by the inclusion maps from $C^\infty(K)$ (I already understand how the topology on *those* spaces is defined) and one as the final *locally convex* topology induced by those maps, i.e. the finest locally convex topology which makes those maps continuous.

I couldn't proof their equivalence, i.e. how do I show that the final topology induced by those maps is already linear and locally convex?

Comment: OK, according to the script Distribution Theory by Ivan F Wilde, the difference between linear, continuous functionals from the Schwartz space and from $C^\infty_K$ is the difference between *tempered* distribution und just distributions.  So I'd like to put more emphasis on the second part of my question, because that's what really puzzled me.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I got a counterexample now, i.e. the final topology w.r.t. to the inclusion maps is not linear.  I only worked it through on ${\bf R}$ though.

The only assumption that I need is that for given $\epsilon>0$ and $k,n\in{\bf N}$ we find some $f\in C^\infty([-1,1])$ such that $\|f^{(j)}\|_\infty<\epsilon$ for $j<k$ and $f^{(k)}(0)>n$, which I think is easily constructable.

Now the set $$A:=\{f\in C^\infty_K:\forall j>0.f(j)<1/f^{(j)}(0)\}$$ (where we set $1/0=\infty$) is open in the final topology, i.e. $A\cap C^\infty([-i,i])$ is open for each $i$.  Yet, if the final topology were linear, we would find an neighbourhood $B$ of $0$ such that $B+B\subseteq A$.  But any such $B$ contains a basic open neighbourhood from $C^\infty([-i,i])$ of the form $$U_i=\{f\in C^\infty([-i,i]):\forall j<k(i).\|f^{(j)}\|_\infty<\epsilon(i)\}$$ for each $i$.  Now we can construct $f\in U_1$ such that $f^{(k(i))}(0)$ is large enough so $f+U_{k(i)+1}\subseteq B+B$ is no longer a subset of $A$.

So the majority of books and scripts I read (e.g. Rudin) got it right, when they defined the topology on the space of test functions as the limit topology *in the category of locally convex spaces*, i.e. the finest *locally convex* topology which makes the inclusion maps continuous.

Answer (score -1):

Let $K_n$ be the unit ball of radius $n$, so your $C_K^\infty = \bigcup_n C^\infty(K_n)$ and let $f_n:C^\infty(K_n)\longmapsto C_K^\infty$ be the natural embeddings. The system
$$
\bigl\{ \bigcup_n f_n[U_n]\, ;\, U_n \text{ is a $0$-neighbourhood in } C^\infty(K_n) \bigr\}
$$
is a filter base in $C_K^\infty$, immediately to verify (using $U_n = f_n^{-1}(f_n[U_n])$) that it is a filter base for a for a fundamental system of $0$-neighbourhoods of a *linear* topology.

An absolutely convex set U is $0$-neighbourhood in $C_K^\infty$ for the topology described above, iff $f_n^{-1}[U]$ is a $0$-neighbourhood in $C^\infty(K_n)$ for each $n$. But the latter is precisely the characterization for a $0$-neighbourhood in the final topology on $C_K^\infty$.

Comment: Do you consider neighbourhoods to be always open?  If not, I'm pretty sure you cannot say in general for a final topology generated by $\{f_i:X_i\rightarrow X\}_i$ that $U$ is $0$-neighbourhood iff all $f^{-1}_i(U)$ are $0$-neighbourhoods in $X_i$, I think I can give a counterexample if you're interested.

Comment: BTW, there might be an answer to my question in cmouhot.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/main.pdf p.14-15 however I haven't been able to verify their solution yet but I'm working on it.

Comment: As long as the $f_n$ are linear, I am sure that the characterization for the final topology is correct.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm wrong, but I thought of the space ${\bf R}^{<\omega}\subseteq{\bf R}^{\omega}$ of finite sequences and the final topology induced by the canonical $f_i:{\bf R}^i\rightarrow{\bf R}^{<\omega}$.  For this space, I'm pretty sure the sets $\{x\in{\bf R}^{<\omega}:|x_i|<\epsilon_i\}$ for $(\epsilon_i)_i\in{\bf R}^{\omega}_+$ form a neighbourhood base around $0$.  But for the set $A:=\cup_i\{x\in{\bf R}^i:\|x\|_\infty<1/i\}$ we have $A\cap{\bf R}^i$ is always a $0$-neighbourhood yet no basic neighbourhood fits into $A$.

Comment: Should have said '$A\cap{\bf R}^i$ is always $0$-neighbourhood *in* ${\bf R}^i$', just to be clear

Comment: For the characterization of final topologies see e.g. section 5.10.5 in Narici, Beckenstein's "Topological Vector Spaces", available online. Actually, I cannot clarify the contradiction to your counterexample...

Comment: I think I have found the "problem": I forgot the condition "absolute convex (i.e. balanced and convex)" for a set $U$ (and edited my answer). And in your example, the set $A$ is not convex.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your filter base, it does not define a linear topology.  If you take $U$ as the union over $U_i:=\{f\in C^\infty(K_i):\|f\|_\infty<1/i\}$ then there should exist a $V$ in your filter base with $V+V\subseteq U$.  But for any such $V$ there exists a non-zero $f$ in $V_1$ and $i>0$ such that $\|f\|_\infty>1/i$, so $f+V_i$ is no subset of $U$.